# Should I store such data in onSaveInstanceState() Bundle?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a `FragmentActivity` with two `Fragments`. The `Activity` receives data through Bluetooth and process it, then the results are showed in different ways on each `Fragment`.

When I open for example a new `Activity` for settings all the data from the previous `Activity` (the one that holds the `Fragments`) is deleted so I need to store it in `onSaveInstanceState()` on the `Activity` to keep the state.

This data are 8 `BitSet` with a size of 16000. Should I save all this data to the `Bundle` in `onSaveInstanceState()` or I will have performance problems delaying my `Activity` startup time significantly? Or I should save this to a `File` or `Database`? I don't need this data once I exit the application, I need to save it to recover the state when a new `Activity` is opened and I lost my previous `Activity` state.

Comment: use a database or a file

Comment: I suspect your problem is that you're running a `replace()` `FragmentTransaction` in onCreate/onStart/onResume, which is why you're losing your data. The fragments and data should still be there when you come back to the Activity, investigate why they're disappearing. (It's useful to enable logging with `FragmentManager.enableDebugLogging(true);`).

Comment: The data is hold in the `Activity`. When I open a new Activity (ie settings) the Activity goes to `onPause()`. When the `Activity` resumes the data is gone (I think dalvik is clearing the resources). The fragments only take the data from the Activity to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BitSet`s with size of 16000 bit have about 2KB (+ some overhead). From the size point of view you dont need to worry about delays when saving this data or reading it.

You should write/read **files**. With files you can store the `BitSet`s in binary form without the need to convert this data somehow in another format. Android's standard blocksize for files is 8KB, so will read and write just one block.

What you should have a closer look, is the startup of the Activity. 16000 bit can be a lot information. Depending on what you do with it, it might take long to build and layout the screen. The tip is, to focus more on a fast `Activity` setup, then on reading/writing a few KB of data.

Answer (score 1):

> When I open for example a new Activity for settings all the data from
>   the previous Activity is deleted so I need to store it in
>   onSavedInstance() on the Activity.

It sounds like you're trying to share data between 2 activities.  So, you would not use onSaveInstance() & Bundle for this.

There are several ways to share data between Activities.  This is something that has been outlined and debated in depth over SO.  They include passing data via an intent, using the Application object to set globally accessible data, and using singleton objects to share data.

Here's the official android documentation on the subject:
http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3

Like I said, which way is best is something that is debated.

Comment: No, I am not trying to share data between Activities, I want to save the state of the Activity so when I open a new one and return to the previous I don't lost the data.